# Apollo useReactiveVar throws TypeError: rv.onNextChange is not a function

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

I have the following variable in `cache.js`:

```
export var isLoggedInVar = () => {
  return localStorage.getItem("token") ? true : false;
};
```

Then, I import the variable in a React functional component and assign it to a reactive variable:

`const value = useReactiveVar(isLoggedInVar)`;

However, upon rendering, if `value` is used, I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: rv.onNextChange is not a function
```

Note, that other variables that are not functions work properly. If nothing's wrong with the variable itself, how can I make this work?

Comment: Hey @Ruham, Can't you just use `isLoggedInVar()` where you need to check the value.? I don't see a reason why you need to use `reactiveVariables` in this case..

Comment: I can, but it doesn't get rendered properly.

Answer (score 1):

Consider wrapping `isLoggedInVar` in `makeVar` hook when declaring it.

```
const isLoggedInVar = makeVar(true)
```